# Coroutine Flow error while retrieving data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

This is the first time I trid imlementing Flow with Firebase using the MVVM Architectural Pattern.
The issue here is when I press loadbutton Data is loaded in the textview. But then when I upload new data and try and get the new data along with the old it doesn't work, It just displays the old data.
After restarting the app it provides with the new data.
Below is the code.

Repository

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class PostsRepository {

    private val mPostsCollection =
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Constants.COLLECTION_POST)

    fun getAllPosts() = flow<State<List<Post>>> {

        emit(State.loading())

        val snapshot = mPostsCollection.get().await()
        val posts = snapshot.toObjects((Post::class.java))

        emit(State.success(posts))

    }.catch {
        emit(State.failed(it.message.toString()))
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)


    fun addPosts(post: Post) = flow<State<DocumentReference>>
    {
        emit(State.loading())

        val postref = mPostsCollection.add(post).await()

        emit(State.success(postref))

    }.catch {
        emit(State.failed(it.message.toString()))
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)


}
```

State Class

```
sealed class State<T> {
    class Loading<T> : State<T>()
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : State<T>()
    data class Failed<T>(val message: String) : State<T>()

    companion object {
        fun <T> loading() = Loading<T>()
        fun <T> success(data: T) = Success(data)
        fun <T> failed(message: String) = Failed<T>(message)

    }

}
```

The ViewModel

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainViewModel(private val repository: PostsRepository):ViewModel() {


   // fun getAllposts() = repository.getAllPosts()

    val getallpostlivedata :LiveData<State<List<Post>>> = repository.getAllPosts().asLiveData()


    fun addpost(post: Post) = repository.addPosts(post)

}
```

The MainActivity

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, MainViewModelFactory()).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        binding.buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(this)

        binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(this)

    }




    private suspend fun addPost(post: Post) {

        viewModel.addpost(post).collect{ state ->
            when (state) {
                is State.Loading -> {
                    showToast("Loading")
                    binding.buttonAdd.isEnabled = false
                }

                is State.Success -> {
                    showToast("Posted")
                    binding.fieldPostContent.setText("")
                    binding.buttonAdd.isEnabled = true
                }

                is State.Failed -> {
                    showToast("Failed! ${state.message}")
                    binding.buttonAdd.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
        }

    }


    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            binding.buttonLoad.id -> {
                uiScope.launch {
                    loadPosts()
                }
            }
            binding.buttonAdd.id -> {
                uiScope.launch {
                    addPost(
                        Post(
                            postContent = binding.fieldPostContent.text.toString(),
                            postAuthor = "Karunesh Palekar"
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private  fun loadPosts() {
        viewModel.getallpostlivedata.observe(this, Observer { state->
           when(state){
               is State.Loading ->{
                   showToast("Loading")
               }
               is State.Success ->{
                   val postText = state.data.joinToString("\n") {
                       "${it.postContent} ~ ${it.postAuthor}"
                   }
                   binding.textPostContent.text = postText
               }
               is State.Failed ->{
                   showToast("Failed! ${state.message}")
               }
           }
        })
    }

    private fun showToast(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

Thank-You for helping out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `getAllPosts()` is returning a `Flow` which is only loading your posts *data at once*. It'll be only loaded when you'll call `collect { }` on that `Flow`.

If you want ***real-time snapshot updates*** of Cloud Firestore then you can update method `getAllPosts()` as below.

```
fun getPostsRealtime() : Flow<State<List<Post>>> = callbackFlow {

    // Register listener
    val listener = addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->

        offer(State.success(snapshot.toObjects(Post::class.java)))

        // If exception occurs, cancel this scope with exception message.
        exception?.let {
            offer(State.error(it.message.toString()))
            cancel(it.message.toString())
        }
    }

    awaitClose {
        // This block is executed when producer channel is cancelled
        // This function resumes with a cancellation exception.

        // Dispose listener
        listener.remove()
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Here, we're using `callbackFlow {}` which allows us to use callback methods and value emission asynchronously.
Hope it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: Yes. I knew that. Will be adding that code in the repo for everyone's reference. Let me know if  Above code works for you or not.